# Can't Clear out a Dropdown Value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown with States, in addition to a blank option. The HTML looks like this:

```
<select id="prime.address.state" name="prime.address.state">
  <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
  <option value="DE" selected="selected">DE:  Delaware</option>
  <option value="HI">HI:  Hawaii</option>
  <option value="PR">PR:  Puerto Rico</option>
  <!-- etc. -->
</select>
```

Initially, the value of DE: Delaware is selected, as shown.

Then, I need to clear out this field when a different radio button is clicked. All the other fields get cleared out, this one does not.

I tried both the val('') setting and the attr('selectedIndex',0). The selection is still on DE: Delaware, rather than blank.

```
$('input[name="prime.address.addressLine1"]').val(""); // OK - Input box    
$('input[name="prime.address.city"]').val(""); // OK - Input box            
$('input[name="prime.address.state"]').attr('selectedIndex', 0); // DOES NOT WORK (State Dropdown)
$('input[name="prime.address.state"]').val(""); // DOES NOT WORK (State Dropdown)
```

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: `.` should not be used in `ID` attribute, rather any attribute.

Comment: yeah Tushar. These JAVA developers ..... all of them make this crazy dot nomenclature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  $('#radio_button').change(function () {
      $("option:selected").prop("selected", false)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="prime.address.state" name="prime.address.state">
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="DE" selected="selected">DE: Delaware</option>
    <option value="HI">HI: Hawaii</option>
    <option value="PR">PR: Puerto Rico</option>
    <!-- etc. -->
</select>
<input type="radio" id="radio_button">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('select[name="prime.address.state"] option:selected').prop('selected', false);
 -----^      ---------------------------^        ----------^
```

Take a look at the arrows ;)

Comment: Good catch, just changing `input` to `select` and calling `.val("")` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the (**.**)

Try this :

```
jQuery('#prime\\.address\\.state').val('')
```

Comment: Wrong! The dots are classnames!!! Who gives you 3 upvotes? Really wrong, facepalm....

Comment: Yes, now it works. However, dots in ids is a fault against the web... It's not your fault, obviously